# How do create enum with Eclipse XSD editor

Tags: xsd, wsimport

I'm creating an XSD for common web service types that will be used in WSDLs.  One of the common types I need is an enum.

**My problem is when I execute wsimport the artifact generated is a class not an enum.**

I'm using Eclipse Indigo's XSD and WSDL editor.  This is what I do in design mode to create my enum:

1. Create new Complex Type (ResponseCodeType)
2. Add new string element (code) in ResponseCodeType
3. In the constraints property of code, I add the following constraint values: SUCCESS, WARNING, ERROR, FATAL

What am I doing wrong?

### XSD source

```
<complexType name="ResponseCodeType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="code">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="string">
                    <enumeration value="SUCCESS"></enumeration>
                    <enumeration value="WARNING"></enumeration>
                    <enumeration value="ERROR"></enumeration>
                    <enumeration value="FATAL"></enumeration>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

### Java source for artifact produced by wsimport

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ResponseCodeType", propOrder = {
    "code"
})
public class ResponseCodeType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String code;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the code property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the code property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCode(String value) {
        this.code = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  When I tried designing my enum I created a complex type with an element having the constraints I needed (SUCCESS, INFO, WARN, ect).

What I did instead was to create a simple type with a string element having the constraints (ResponseCode).  Then I created a complex type (ResponseCodeType) with an element of ResponseCode.

When I executed wsimport, it generated ResponseCode as an enum and ResponseCodeType class with a ResponseCode attribute.

If anyone has a better approch please comment or provide a better answer.